# Correct library version for x64 and Win32 platform

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, command-line, odbc

I want to create a console application with VS 2010, that uses odbccp32.lib.
I want to create both 32 and 64 bit versions of command line application.
In the Linker properties of this project, there is odbccp32.lib from Inherited values for Additional Dependencies.
My question is, does VS pick up correct odbccp32.lib for both x64 and Win32 platforms.
What is the path from which it will pick up the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows SDK has separate .lib files for x86 and x64. Make sure your linker folders are setup correctly such that it's trying to use the x86 .lib files when building for x64.

Try to read this article on MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b8315ae6-83f6-406c-9629-b95cbb6b9713/weird-linking-errors-when-compiling-x64-bit?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: I enabled /VERBOSE:Lib and could see that my application is picking up correct libraries for different platforms.

Comment: Can you run a dependency walker and see that you are using the correct   .dll?